# How to summarize dates in a table with different timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

When I ask this question, I get multiple hits on divcode because there are different timestamps in pickdate. Is there a way to get the question to summarize the date so I get 1 value per division?

```
/*
Söker Vikt och volym Snitt
*/

select  TO_CHAR(ROUND(O08T1.pickdate),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_1,
       O08T1.divcode,
       sum(O08T1.calcwght) as Vikt, sum(O08T1.calcvol) as Volym,
       count(*) as AntalOrder,
       avg(O08T1.calcwght) as avg_vikt,
       avg(O08T1.calcvol) as avg_Vol

from O08T1
where O08T1.pickdate >= @('Från datum',#DATE)
group by O08T1.pickdate, O08T1.divcode
order by Pickdate DESC
```

Comment: If you want one result per divcode then just don't include pickdate in the select list or group-by. If you want want one per divcode per day then make the group-by (and order-by) round the date, as the select list is. Unclear what you mean though. Sample data and current/expected results might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values grouped by day then don't use `GROUP BY pickdate` as that will group by each instant and have values down to an accuracy of a second. Instead, `GROUP BY TRUNC(pickdate)` which will truncate values to the start of the day and will aggregate all values on the same day together (and then, also, use `TRUNC` in the first line and in the `ORDER BY`):

```sql
select TO_CHAR(TRUNC(pickdate),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_1,
       divcode,
       sum(calcwght) as Vikt,
       sum(calcvol) as Volym,
       count(*) as AntalOrder,
       avg(calcwght) as avg_vikt,
       avg(calcvol) as avg_Vol
from   O08T1
where  pickdate >= @('Från datum',#DATE)
group by TRUNC(pickdate),
         divcode
order by TRUNC(pickdate) DESC
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you accept/upvote the answer, then, @Filip?